# IF Exist Do Statement (Batch File)

Tags: windows, batch-file

Please could someone give me an example in batch of something like:

IF test.txt EXISTS DO start test.txt

Comment: http://www.computerhope.com/if.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example -

```
IF EXIST test.txt start test.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do `if /?` or `help if`, you know.

```
if exists file command
```

For multiple commands (or when using `else`), enclose them with parentheses, i.e.

```
if exists file (
    command1
    command2
)
```

Comment: @James: && means command2 will only run if the exit code of the command1 process is 0, use command1 & command2 to run command2 no matter what